# Applying additional oauth scopes to coinbase

Tags: development, coinbase.com, website-integration

I am trying to apply the coinbase wallet API with oauth to use its send functionality. I have been able to connect to the API and use its endpoints, but whenever I try to use the send functionality, I am thrown the error `Invalid amount for meta[send_limit_amount]`. My omniauth initializer looks like this:

```
provider :coinbase, , ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'], 
scope: 'wallet:user:read wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read wallet:transactions:send'
```

The reason for this error is because, in order to use the send functionality, coinbase requires additional parameter `meta[send_limit_amount]`. Where and how am I supposed to apply this additional scope?

Answer (score 0):

Old posting, but hit this and this was the first Google result so worth updating.  You can append the meta values to the redirect URL:

`meta[send_limit_amount]=50&meta[send_limit_currency]=USD&meta[send_limit_period]=day`

This is buried in the OAuth2 docs on the Coinbase site.